# Scipy for loop Ttest from dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe mmLog:

```
                  Experiment       Logmm
0               Spontaneous1       0.022815
1                     Light1       0.007222
2                       PTZ1       0.03168
3               Spontaneous1       0.015003
4                     Light1       0.013402
5                       PTZ1       0.021539
...                      ...            ...
38072  SpontaneousControl147       0.013685
38073  SpontaneousControl147       0.034702
38074  SpontaneousControl147       0.008993
```

I would like to run a ttest from each unique group and compare it to the control group in the Experiment column. I have tried to create a dictionary of unique identifier dataframes

```
df_uniq = dict()
for k, v in mmLog.groupby('Experiment'):
    df_uniq[k] = v
```

and then use the for loop

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

for key in df_uniq: 
    cat1 = key
    cat2 = df[df['Experiment']=='SpontaneousControl147']
    ttest_ind(cat1['Logmm'], cat2['Logmm'])
```

and get TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: So from the code you've provided you're adding the groupby results to the dict `df_names` instead of `df_uniq`, is this intentional?

Comment: No that was a mistake. I copy and pasted the wrong code . It is updated now.

Comment: Where is `mm Log10(n+1)` coming from?

Comment: It is a column in the DataFrame not shown in his snippet, you can see it being used to access a column in the control as well.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz. Understood. I was implying that it should be shown for a complete example.

Comment: That should be updated now for clarity. Sorry about that. Im new to the formatting here.

Comment: @Mark. I've posted what I think is a much simpler way to do this. Any time you find yourself devolving into python standard library and built in types when working with numpy and pandas, is a time to step back and ask if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign the values from the dict, not its keys, to `cat1`:

```py
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

results = {}
for key, val in df_uniq.items(): 
    cat1 = val
    cat2 = df[df['Experiment']=='SpontaneousControl147']
    results[key] = ttest_ind(cat1['Logmm'], cat2['Logmm'])
```

By assigning the key to `cat1`, you are trying to perform the T-test on a string instead of the groupby result.

Edit: You can also pull the line assigning `cat2` out of the loop since that only needs to be done once :)

Comment: The output now is just one tstat and pvalue I though it might give me a list per condition in the loop?

Comment: I've updated it to generate a results dict where each experiment has the tuple of tstat and pvalue associated with it. If you want it in a list instead, simply change the key assignments with a list.append call :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making this more complicated than it needs to be. [`pd.Dataframe.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returns a [`pd.GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) object that has all the properties you need, and more. There is no need to create redundant custom dictionaries.

For example, start with

```
groups = mmLog.groupby('Experiment')
```

Now `groups.get_group('SpontaneousControl147')` will have all the elements of the control group:

```
>>> control = groups.get_group('SpontaneousControl147')['Logmm']
>>> control
38072    0.013685
38073    0.034702
38074    0.008993
Name: Logmm, dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, you can focus on just the column you care about with `groups['logmm']`, which will return a `SeriesGroupBy` object that you can get the control data from:

```
control = groups['Logmm'].get_group('SpontaneousControl147')
```

In both cases, `groups` supports direct iteration as well as an `apply` method. If you don't need to aggregate the results:

```
for key, subset in groups:
    if key == 'SpontaneousControl147':
        continue
    ttest(control, subset['Logmm'])
```

If you want to build a `Series` of ttest values:

```
groups['Logmm'].apply(lambda data: ttest(control, data))
```

OR

```
groups.apply(lambda df: ttest(control, df['Logmm']))
```

Here are the two TL;DR versions:

1. Using the full `DataFrameGroupBy`:

   ```
   groups = mmLog.groupby('Experiment')
   control = groups.get_group('SpontaneousControl147')['Logmm']
   result = groups.apply(lambda df: ttest(control, df['Logmm']))
   ```
2. Using the `SeriesGroupBy` for the column of interest:

   ```
   groups = mmLog.groupby('Experiment')['Logmm']
   control = groups.get_group('SpontaneousControl147')
   result = groups.apply(lamda s: ttest(control, s))
   ```